# Diagonalisability of an operator when its range and null space are independent.

Tags: linear-algebra

$T$ is a linear operator on a finite dimensional Vector space over $F$ with range $R$ and null space $N$. If $V$ is the direct sum of $R$ and $N$, is $T$ diagonalizable over $F$? I have proved the converse of this problem. For solving this problem I am stuck. Please help.

Comment: Is every invertible operator diagonalisable?

Comment: Thank you for your hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is false. Here the counterexample:

Take the operator $T:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ represented via the matrix:
\begin{equation}
\left[
\begin{matrix}
1 & 1\\
0 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right]
\end{equation}

The range $R$ is $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the null-space $N$ is $\{0\}$; so $\mathbb{R^2} = R\oplus N$, but $T$ is not diagonalizable.

Comment: Thank you for the counter example